What function does `CreateIconFromResourceEx()` use to decompress PNG resources?
Icons in .dll or .exe files are stored in the resources segment as Windows DIBs or PNGs since Windows Vista.
What function/library is used by the CreateIconFromResourceEx() WinAPI function in the user32.dll to read/decompress these PNG resources?
Does CreateIconFromResourceEx() use the WIC for this purpose ?

What OS version? It's bound to be an implementation detail that might change over time...

@DanMašek: Win10 or Win7... Whatever you like.

PNG uses DEFLATE, so it's likely they would use an implmenentation of it.

From what I can see, Windows 7, 10 & 11 implementation in user32.dll call an internal function called ConvertPNGToDIBIcon which itselfs defers to what's registered in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows under the key IconServiceLib, which points to an IconCodecService.dll which uses WIC.

@KenWhite PNG support for icons was introduced in Windows Vista. The Windows Imaging Component was also introduced in Windows Vista (with in-box PNG encoders and decoders). There's no inherent reason why the version of CreateIconFromResourceEx in Windows Vista couldn't use the WIC.

@SimonMourier:  Thanks Simon, that is the answer I have been looking for.  Also, I appreciate that you noticed that WIC was introduced at the same time as PNG icons in Windows Vista, IInspectable.

It looks like USER32.dll!ConvertDIBIcon() calls ConvertPNGToDIBIcon() and IconCodecService.dll does not export any functions - not even by an ordinal !

@GeorgeRobinson why do you need to know?

Indeed, you can't reuse IconCodecService, it calls "back" a special user32 exported function (PrivateRegisterICSProc) in DllMain to register itself to user32 so user32 code can use it...

@Jabberwocky To discover (part of) its inherent pre- and postconditions. This knowledge can inform designing a replacement stripped of accidental complexity and inefficiency.

@Jabberwocky: It's off topic but I want to discover the internals and eventually write my own CreateIconFromResourceEx() because the Microsoft's one is buggy, i.e. it does not load the original icon image from the resource.  It insists on changing its color format and stretching its dimensions even when the LR_DEFAULTSIZE flag is NOT set and  cxDesired==0 and cyDesired==0.  I get off-by-1 pixel errors.

@Simon. Yeah, I saw it. It puts the address of IconCodecService.dll!ConvertToDIBProc() into  the variable user32.dll!gpICSProc

According to Simon Mourier's suggestion:
Windows 7, 10 & 11 implementation in user32.dll call an internal function called ConvertPNGToDIBIcon which itselfs defers to what's registered in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows under the key IconServiceLib, which points to an IconCodecService.dll which uses WIC.

I appreciate your answer but I cannot accept it because it does not explore the issue deeply enough.

When a function like the CreateIconFromResourceEx() is called, user32.dll sometimes dynamically loads another DLL specified in the REG_SZ value HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows\IconServiceLib.
This load can be triggered with a function like the one below:
bool TriggerICSLoad()
{
    if (PCHAR pc = (PCHAR)GlobalAlloc(GMEM_FIXED | GMEM_ZEROINIT, 40)) {
        strcpy_s(pc, 39, "‰PNG\r\n\x1a\n"); //89 50 4E 47 OD 0A 1A 0A
        CreateIconFromResourceEx((PBYTE)pc, 40, true, 0x00030000, 0, 0, LR_DEFAULTCOLOR);  //Trigger the loading of the ICS library
        GlobalFree(pc);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

This causes a private variable user32.dll!gpICSProc to be set to an address of a private function ConvertToDIBProc() residing inside the ...\IconServiceLib which is set by default to IconCodecService.dll.
This is initiated by the IconCodecService.dll!DllMain() that calls the exported function user32.dll!PrivateRegisterICSProc() which looks like this:
bool PrivateRegisterICSProc(PCONVERT_TO_DIB_PROC AddrOfFn)
{
  if ( user32.dll!gpICSProc )
    return false;

  user32.dll!gpICSProc = ddrOfFn;
  return true;
}

From the above, you can see that checking whether the ...\IconServiceLib has already been loaded by user32.dll can be done at any time by calling the following function without any side effects:
bool IsICSLoaded()
{    
    if (HMODULE hModUSR = GetModuleHandle(L"user32.dll") )
    {
        if (PREGISTER_ICS_PROC pRegisterICSProc = (PREGISTER_ICS_PROC)GetProcAddress(hModUSR, "PrivateRegisterICSProc") )
            return !(pRegisterICSProc)(0);
    }

    return false;
}

The ConvertToDIBProc() residing in the IconCodecService.dll is not exported nor documented but I reverse engineered it and it looks like this:
HGLOBAL ConvertToDIBProc(PBYTE pbBuffer, DWORD cbBufferSize, DWORD* pcbOutputSize, DWORD Flags)
{
    if (CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED | COINIT_SPEED_OVER_MEMORY | COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE) >=0)   // In the original this is actually called in USER32.DLL
        return 0;

    for (unsigned char* p = pbBuffer; (p < pbBuffer + cbBufferSize); *(volatile unsigned char*)p, p += 4096);  // Touch every page of the buffer

    IWICImagingFactory* pIWICImagingFactory = NULL;
    WICPixelFormatGUID PixelFormat = GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppBGRA;
    IWICStream* pStreamIn = NULL;
    IWICBitmapDecoder* instBitmapDecoder = NULL;
    IWICBitmapDecoderInfo* pBitmapDecoderInfo = NULL;
    IWICComponentInfo* ppDecoderIInfo = NULL;
    IWICComponentInfo* ppIInfoEncoder = NULL;
    IWICBitmapEncoderInfo* pBitmapEncoderInfo = NULL;
    IWICBitmapEncoder* instBitmapEncoder = NULL;
    IWICBitmapFrameEncode* pBitmapFrameEncoder = NULL;
    IWICBitmapFrameDecode* pBitmapFrameDecode = NULL;
    IWICPalette* pPalette = NULL;
    HGLOBAL phglobal = NULL;
    LPSTREAM pStreamOut = NULL;
    int ExtraMemory;
    WICRect rc;
    HRESULT hr;

    if ( !(Flags & 0x80000003) )
        goto CLEANUP;

    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_WICImagingFactory, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pIWICImagingFactory));
    if (hr < 0) goto CLEANUP;    
    hr = pIWICImagingFactory->CreateStream(&pStreamIn);
    if (hr < 0) goto CLEANUP;
    hr = pStreamIn->InitializeFromMemory(pbBuffer, cbBufferSize);   
    if (hr < 0) goto CLEANUP;
    hr = CreateStreamOnHGlobal(0, 0, &pStreamOut);
    if (hr < 0) goto CLEANUP;

    IID cls_WICDecoder;
    if (Flags & 1) 
        cls_WICDecoder = CLSID_WICPngDecoder;
    else
    {
        cls_WICDecoder = CLSID_WICJpegDecoder;
        if (!(Flags & 2))
            cls_WICDecoder = CLSID_NULL;
    }
    
    hr = pIWICImagingFactory->CreateComponentInfo(cls_WICDecoder, &ppDecoderIInfo);
    if (hr < 0) goto CLEANUP;   
    hr = ppDecoderIInfo->QueryInterface(IID_IWICBitmapDecoderInfo, (LPVOID*)(&pBitmapDecoderInfo));
    if (hr < 0) goto CLEANUP;    
    hr = pBitmapDecoderInfo->CreateInstance(&instBitmapDecoder);
    if (hr < 0) goto CLEANUP;
    hr = instBitmapDecoder->Initialize(pStreamIn, WICDecodeMetadataCacheOnDemand);   // IWICBitmapDecoder::Initialize
    if (hr < 0) goto CLEANUP;

    UINT FrameCount;
    hr = instBitmapDecoder->GetFrameCount(&FrameCount);             // IWICBitmapDecoder::GetFrameCount
    if ((hr < 0) || (!(FrameCount))) goto CLEANUP;
    hr = instBitmapDecoder->GetFrame(0, &pBitmapFrameDecode);       // IWICBitmapDecoder::GetFrame
    if (hr < 0) goto CLEANUP;

    UINT pixWidth;
    int pixHeight;
    hr = pBitmapFrameDecode->GetSize(&pixWidth, (UINT*)&pixHeight); // IWICBitmapFrameDecode::GetSize
    if (hr < 0) goto CLEANUP;

    double DPI_x;
    double DPI_y;
    hr = pBitmapFrameDecode->GetResolution(&DPI_x, &DPI_y);         // IWICBitmapFrameDecode::GetResolution
    if (hr < 0) goto CLEANUP;

    if (Flags & 2)
    {
        hr = pBitmapFrameDecode->GetPixelFormat(&PixelFormat);      // IWICBitmapFrameDecode::GetPixelFormat
        if (hr<0) goto CLEANUP;

        if (PixelFormat == GUID_WICPixelFormat8bppGray)
            PixelFormat = GUID_WICPixelFormat24bppBGR;
        else
            PixelFormat = GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppBGRA;
    }

    ExtraMemory = 0;
    if (Flags & 0x80000000)
    {
        UINT cbWidthColor;
        UINT cbWidthMono;
        UINT pixHeightAbs;

        if (PixelFormat == GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppBGRA)
            cbWidthColor = ((32 * pixWidth + 31) >> 3) & 0xFFFFFFFC;
        else if (PixelFormat == GUID_WICPixelFormat24bppBGR)
            cbWidthColor = ((24 * pixWidth + 31) >> 3) & 0xFFFFFFFC;
        else
            goto CLEANUP;
       
        cbWidthMono = ((pixWidth + 31) >> 3) & 0xFFFFFFFC;
        pixHeightAbs = pixHeight>=0 ? pixHeight : -pixHeight;

        if (pixHeightAbs && (cbWidthMono < 0xFFFFFFFF / pixHeightAbs) && (cbWidthColor < 0xFFFFFFFF / pixHeightAbs) )
            ExtraMemory = cbWidthMono * pixHeightAbs;
    }

    hr = pIWICImagingFactory->CreateComponentInfo(CLSID_WICBmpEncoder, &ppIInfoEncoder);            // IWICImagingFactory::CreateComponentInfo
    if (hr < 0) goto CLEANUP;
    hr = ppIInfoEncoder->QueryInterface(IID_IWICBitmapEncoderInfo, (LPVOID*)&pBitmapEncoderInfo);   // IWICComponentInfo::QueryInterface
    if (hr < 0) goto CLEANUP;   
    hr = pBitmapEncoderInfo->CreateInstance(&instBitmapEncoder);                // IWICBitmapEncoderInfo::CreateInstance
    if (hr < 0) goto CLEANUP;   
    hr = instBitmapEncoder->Initialize(pStreamOut, WICBitmapEncoderNoCache);    // IWICBitmapEncoder::Initialize
    if (hr < 0) goto CLEANUP;
    hr = instBitmapEncoder->CreateNewFrame(&pBitmapFrameEncoder, NULL);         // IWICBitmapEncoder::CreateNewFrame
    if (hr < 0) goto CLEANUP;
    hr = pBitmapFrameEncoder->Initialize(NULL);              // IWICBitmapFrameEncode::Initialize
    if (hr < 0) goto CLEANUP;
    hr = pBitmapFrameEncoder->SetSize(pixWidth, pixHeight);  // IWICBitmapFrameEncode::SetSize
    if (hr < 0) goto CLEANUP;
    hr = pBitmapFrameEncoder->SetPixelFormat(&PixelFormat);  // IWICBitmapFrameEncode::SetPixelFormat
    if (hr < 0) goto CLEANUP;
    hr = pBitmapFrameEncoder->SetResolution(DPI_x, DPI_y);   // IWICBitmapFrameEncode::SetResolution
    if (hr < 0) goto CLEANUP;
    hr = pIWICImagingFactory->CreatePalette(&pPalette);      // IWICImagingFactory::CreatePalette
    if (hr >= 0)
    {
        hr = pBitmapFrameDecode->CopyPalette(pPalette); // IWICBitmapFrameDecode::CopyPalette

        if (hr != WINCODEC_ERR_PALETTEUNAVAILABLE)
        {
            if (hr >= 0)
            {
                hr = pBitmapFrameEncoder->SetPalette(pPalette);
                if (hr < 0)
                    goto CLEANUP;
            }
            else
                goto CLEANUP;
        }                     
    }
    
    rc = {0,0,(int)pixWidth,pixHeight};

    hr = pBitmapFrameEncoder->WriteSource(pBitmapFrameDecode, &rc); //IWICBitmapFrameEncode::WriteSource
    if (hr < 0) goto CLEANUP;
    hr = pBitmapFrameEncoder->Commit();  // IWICBitmapFrameEncode::Commit
    if (hr < 0) goto CLEANUP;
    hr = instBitmapEncoder->Commit();    // IWICBitmapEncoder::Commit
    if (hr < 0) goto CLEANUP;
    hr = GetHGlobalFromStream(pStreamOut, &phglobal);
    if (hr < 0) goto CLEANUP;                                                                                      
    
    if (phglobal)
    {
        size_t GlobSize = GlobalSize(phglobal);
        if (GlobSize > 54)
        {
            if (ExtraMemory)
            {
                HGLOBAL hReAllocated = GlobalReAlloc(phglobal, ExtraMemory + GlobSize, 0);// HGLOBAL, Size, idDecoder
                if (!hReAllocated)
                {
                    GlobalFree(phglobal);
                    phglobal = 0;
                    goto CLEANUP;
                }
                phglobal = hReAllocated;
            }
            if (pcbOutputSize)
                *pcbOutputSize = (DWORD)GlobSize;
        }
    }

CLEANUP:
    if (pPalette)
        pPalette->Release();
    if (pBitmapFrameEncoder)
        pBitmapFrameEncoder->Release();
    if (pBitmapEncoderInfo)
        pBitmapEncoderInfo->Release();
    if (ppDecoderIInfo)
        ppDecoderIInfo->Release();
    if (ppIInfoEncoder)
        ppIInfoEncoder->Release();
    if (instBitmapEncoder)
        instBitmapEncoder->Release();
    if (pBitmapFrameDecode)
        pBitmapFrameDecode->Release();
    if (pBitmapDecoderInfo)
        pBitmapDecoderInfo->Release();
    if (instBitmapDecoder)
        instBitmapDecoder->Release();
    if (pIWICImagingFactory)
        pIWICImagingFactory->Release();
    if (pStreamIn)
        pStreamIn->Release();
    if (pStreamOut)
        pStreamOut->Release();

    CoUninitialize();   // In the original this is actually called in USER32.DLL

    return phglobal;
}

The function above takes a pointer to a memory buffer that contains a PNG or JPEG image and returns a memory handle (HGLOBAL) to a Windows Device Independent Bitmap (DIB) consisting of the BITMAPFILEHEADER, BITMAPINFOHEADER and pixel array.  It does this by using the Windows Imaging component (WIC) extensively.
This function also takes the Flags parameter which has the following meanings:
0x00000000 : disallowed
0x00000001 : Convert PNG to 32bppBGRA DIB
0x00000002 : Convert 8bppGray JPEG to 24bppBGR DIB (convert all other JPEG formats to 32bppBGRA DIB).
0x00000003 : Convert 8bppGray PNG to 24bppBGR DIB (convert all other PNG formats to 32bppBGRA DIB).
0x80000000 : OR it (bitwise) with the remaining flags to allocate extra memory for a monochrome bitmap of the same dimensions (The extra memory count is not written to *pcbOutputSize but it is visible to GlobalSize(). This flag cannot be used alone).

Because the address of the ConvertToDIBProc() is not exported, you can call it only by using extreme ways, as illustrated below:
HGLOBAL ConvertToDIBProcEw(PBYTE pbBuffer, DWORD cbBufferSize, DWORD* pcbOutputSize, DWORD Flags)  
{
    static PCONVERT_TO_DIB_PROC gpConvertToDIBProc = NULL;

    if (!(pbBuffer) || !(cbBufferSize) || !(pcbOutputSize) || !(Flags))
        return 0;

    if (gpConvertToDIBProc)
    {
        return (gpConvertToDIBProc)(pbBuffer, cbBufferSize, pcbOutputSize, Flags);
    }
    else
    {
        PDLL_NOTIFICATION_CONTEXT pContext = (PDLL_NOTIFICATION_CONTEXT)_alloca(sizeof(DLL_NOTIFICATION_CONTEXT));  //This must be allocated on the stack or it will fail the subsequent IsAddrOnStack() check.
        *pContext = { NULL, L"PrivateRegisterICSProc", L"user32.dll", &LocalRegisterICSProc }; 
        if (GetICSLibraryName(&pContext->pLibFileName))
        {
            if (IsICSLoaded())
            {                
                if (HMODULE hModICS = GetModuleHandle(pContext->pLibFileName))
                {
                    pContext->hMod = hModICS;
                    if (HMODULE hModUSR = GetModuleHandle(pContext->pImportedModuleName))
                    {

                        PCHAR pc = wctombs(pContext->pImportedFunctionName);
                        if (__int64* op = (__int64*)GetProcAddress(hModUSR, pc))
                        {
                            INT32 ofs;
                            if ((*op & 0x0000000000FFFFFF) == 0x00000000003d8348)  //check for the CMP [RIP+ofs],0 opcode
                            {
                                ofs = (INT32)((*op & 0x00FFFFFFFF000000) >> 24) + 8;  //extract RIP relative offset of gpICSProc from the CMP qword ptr [RIP + ofs],0 opcode.
                                PDWORD pFn = *(PDWORD*)((PBYTE)op + ofs);
                                if (IsAddrInExecutableSection(hModICS, pFn))
                                {
                                    if (((*pFn & 0xC7FFFB) == 0x00C48B48) || ((*pFn & 0xF8FFFE) == 0x00E08948)) // check for: MOV reg64,RSP (it has 2 synonymous encodings, sheesh!)
                                        gpConvertToDIBProc = (PCONVERT_TO_DIB_PROC)pFn;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        free(pc);
                    }

                    if (!gpConvertToDIBProc)   //Try an alternative method to obtain the address of ConvertToDIBProc() if the method above failed.
                    {
                        PMY_LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY pLdrDataTableEntry = NULL;
                        if ((LdrFindEntryForAddress(hModICS, &pLdrDataTableEntry) == STATUS_SUCCESS) && (pLdrDataTableEntry) && (hModICS == pLdrDataTableEntry->DllBase))
                        {
                            pLdrDataTableEntry->Padding1 = MY_LODWORD(pContext);
                            pLdrDataTableEntry->Padding2 = MY_HIDWORD(pContext);

                            if (IsAddrInExecutableSection(hModICS, pLdrDataTableEntry->EntryPoint))
                                pContext->pOrgDllEntryPoint = pLdrDataTableEntry->EntryPoint;
                            else
                            {
                                PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS NtHeader = ImageNtHeader((PVOID)hModICS);
                                if (NtHeader)
                                {
                                    PLDR_INIT_ROUTINE AddressOfEntryPoint = (PLDR_INIT_ROUTINE)((PBYTE)hModICS + NtHeader->OptionalHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint);
                                    if (IsAddrInExecutableSection(hModICS, AddressOfEntryPoint))
                                    {
                                        pContext->pOrgDllEntryPoint = AddressOfEntryPoint;

                                        if ( (pContext->pOrgImpProcAddress = (PREGISTER_ICS_PROC)SetImpProcAddress((PBYTE)hModICS, pContext->pImportedFunctionName, pContext->pImportedModuleName, &LocalRegisterICSProc)))
                                        {
                                            (pContext->pOrgDllEntryPoint)(hModICS, DLL_PROCESS_DETACH, NULL);  //So the CRT is not initialized twice
                                            (pContext->pOrgDllEntryPoint)(hModICS, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, NULL);  //This causes LocalRegisterICSProc() to be called

                                            if (pContext->pOrgImpProcAddress) //Just in case the LocalRegisterICSProc() has not restored the imports
                                            {
                                                SetImpProcAddress((PBYTE)hModICS, pContext->pImportedFunctionName, pContext->pImportedModuleName, pContext->pOrgImpProcAddress);  //Restore IAT
                                                ((PREGISTER_ICS_PROC)pContext->pOrgImpProcAddress)((PCONVERT_TO_DIB_PROC)pContext->Result); //Call the original imported function (the PrivateRegisterICSProc() )
                                            }

                                            gpConvertToDIBProc = (PCONVERT_TO_DIB_PROC)pContext->Result;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        
                    }
                }
            }
            else  //if (!IsICSLoaded())
            {
                if (LdrRegisterDllNotification(0, &DllNotificationCallback, pContext, &pContext->cookie) == STATUS_SUCCESS)
                {
                    TriggerICSLoad();

                    if (pContext->cookie) //In case LocalDllInitRoutine() did not clean it up
                        LdrUnregisterDllNotification(pContext->cookie);

                    if (pContext->pOrgImpProcAddress) //In case LocalRegisterICSProc() has not restored the imports
                    {
                        if (HMODULE hModICS = GetModuleHandle(pContext->pLibFileName))
                            SetImpProcAddress((PBYTE)hModICS, pContext->pImportedFunctionName, pContext->pImportedModuleName, pContext->pOrgImpProcAddress);
                    }

                    if (IsICSLoaded())
                        gpConvertToDIBProc = (PCONVERT_TO_DIB_PROC)pContext->Result;
                }
            }

            free((PVOID)pContext->pLibFileName);
        }
    }

    if (gpConvertToDIBProc)
        return (gpConvertToDIBProc)(pbBuffer, cbBufferSize, pcbOutputSize, Flags);
    else
        return 0;
}

bool __declspec(noinline) LocalRegisterICSProc(PCONVERT_TO_DIB_PROC pConvertToDIBProc)    //If this function is inlined then IsAddrOnStack() may fail
{
    PMY_LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY pLdrDataTableEntry=NULL;
    if ((LdrFindEntryForAddress(_ReturnAddress(), &pLdrDataTableEntry) == STATUS_SUCCESS) && (pLdrDataTableEntry))
    {        
        PDLL_NOTIFICATION_CONTEXT pContext = (PDLL_NOTIFICATION_CONTEXT)((ULONGLONG)pLdrDataTableEntry->Padding1 | (((ULONGLONG)pLdrDataTableEntry->Padding2) << 32));
        HMODULE hModICS = (HMODULE)pLdrDataTableEntry->DllBase;
        if (IsAddrOnStack(pContext) && (pContext->hMod == hModICS))  //Sanity check
        {
            pContext->Result = pConvertToDIBProc;

            if (PREGISTER_ICS_PROC pOrgImpProcAddress = (PREGISTER_ICS_PROC)pContext->pOrgImpProcAddress)
            {
                pContext->pOrgImpProcAddress = NULL;

                if (IsAddrInExecutableSection(GetModuleHandle(pContext->pImportedModuleName), pOrgImpProcAddress))
                {
                    SetImpProcAddress((PBYTE)hModICS, pContext->pImportedFunctionName, pContext->pImportedModuleName, pOrgImpProcAddress);  //Restore import
                    return (pOrgImpProcAddress)(pConvertToDIBProc);
                }
            
            }
        }
    }

    return false; // 
}

bool __declspec(noinline) LocalDllInitRoutine(_In_ PVOID DllHandle, _In_ ULONG Reason, _In_opt_ PVOID Context) //If this function is inlined then IsAddrOnStack() may fail
{
    BOOLEAN res = false;

    PMY_LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY pLdrDataTableEntry=NULL;
    if ((LdrFindEntryForAddress(DllHandle, &pLdrDataTableEntry) == STATUS_SUCCESS) && (pLdrDataTableEntry) && (pLdrDataTableEntry->DllBase == DllHandle))
    {
        PDLL_NOTIFICATION_CONTEXT pContext = (PDLL_NOTIFICATION_CONTEXT)((ULONGLONG)pLdrDataTableEntry->Padding1 | (((ULONGLONG)pLdrDataTableEntry->Padding2) << 32));        
        if (IsAddrOnStack(pContext) && (pContext->hMod == DllHandle))   //Sanity check
        {
            PLDR_INIT_ROUTINE pOrgDllEntryPoint = pContext->pOrgDllEntryPoint;
            if ((pOrgDllEntryPoint) && IsAddrInExecutableSection((HMODULE)DllHandle, pOrgDllEntryPoint))  //Sanity check
            {
                if (Reason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH)
                {
                    if (pContext->cookie)
                    {
                        LdrUnregisterDllNotification(pContext->cookie);
                        pContext->cookie = NULL;
                    }

                    pContext->pOrgImpProcAddress = SetImpProcAddress((PBYTE)DllHandle, pContext->pImportedFunctionName, pContext->pImportedModuleName, pContext->pNewImpProcAddress);
                }

                res = (*pOrgDllEntryPoint)(DllHandle, Reason, Context); //Call the original DLL Entry Point
            }                     
        }
    }

    return res;
}


VOID CALLBACK DllNotificationCallback(_In_ ULONG NotificationReason, _In_ PLDR_DLL_NOTIFICATION_DATA pNotificationData, _In_opt_ PDLL_NOTIFICATION_CONTEXT pContext)
{
    if ( (pContext) && (NotificationReason == LDR_DLL_NOTIFICATION_REASON_LOADED) )
    {
        printf("LOAD NOTIFY: %ws\n", pNotificationData->Loaded.FullDllName->Buffer);

        if (!_wcsnicmp(pContext->pLibFileName, pNotificationData->Loaded.BaseDllName->Buffer, pNotificationData->Loaded.BaseDllName->Length) || !_wcsnicmp(pContext->pLibFileName, pNotificationData->Loaded.FullDllName->Buffer, pNotificationData->Loaded.FullDllName->Length ))
        {
            pContext->hMod = (HMODULE)pNotificationData->Loaded.DllBase;

            if (bitness(pContext->hMod) != 64)
            {
                printf("ERROR: Handling non-64bit DLLs is not implemented\n");
                pContext->Result = NULL;
                return;
            }

            PMY_LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY pLdrDataTableEntry = NULL;
            if ((LdrFindEntryForAddress(pContext->hMod, &pLdrDataTableEntry) == STATUS_SUCCESS) && (pLdrDataTableEntry) && (pContext->hMod == pLdrDataTableEntry->DllBase))
            {                
                pLdrDataTableEntry->Padding1 = MY_LODWORD(pContext);
                pLdrDataTableEntry->Padding2 = MY_HIDWORD(pContext);
                pContext->pOrgDllEntryPoint = pLdrDataTableEntry->EntryPoint;
                pLdrDataTableEntry->EntryPoint = &LocalDllInitRoutine;  // Needed because this dll notification is invoked BEFORE the imports are resolved in Windows 7.
            }
            else
                pContext->Result = NULL;
        }
    }
}

typedef struct _DLL_NOTIFICATION_CONTEXT
{
    LPCWSTR pLibFileName;
    LPCWSTR pImportedFunctionName;
    LPCWSTR pImportedModuleName;
    PVOID pNewImpProcAddress;
    HMODULE hMod;
    PVOID pOrgImpProcAddress;    
    PLDR_INIT_ROUTINE pOrgDllEntryPoint;
    PVOID cookie;
    PVOID Result;
} DLL_NOTIFICATION_CONTEXT, * PDLL_NOTIFICATION_CONTEXT;

The function listed above works only in 64-bit Windows. If you are interested in the various helper functions called by it, write me so in the comments.

This answer will be accepted if it receives any positive votes

TriggerICSLoad could be changed to this: void TriggerICSLoad() { BYTE png_stub[] = "‰PNG\r\n\x1a\n\0"; CreateIconFromResourceEx( png_stub, _countof(png_stub), TRUE, 0x00030000, 0, 0, LR_DEFAULTCOLOR ); }. I haven't had time to look over the rest of this proposed answer. I will if desired.

@IInspectable:  Thanks for taking a look.  I chose to implement TriggerICSLoad() with HGLOBAL because I've seen CreateIconFromResourceEx() useGlobalReAlloc() internally.  I did not debug it deep enough to see if it gets to that place, so I just played it safe in case it does.  Also, LoadResource()returns HGLOBAL and the documentation of CreateIconFromResourceEx() suggests that its presbits argument often comes from LoadResource() etc... If it does not use HGLOBAL internally, then your version of  TriggerICSLoad() is better, of course.

@IInspectable: Also, if (_countof(png_stub) < 40 ) then the ICS library does NOT get loaded.
